# $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} \frac{f_n^{(n)}(\frac{1}{n})}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I just try to solve a problem, but I'm not sure it's right or not.

Here is the problem:

Suppose $f_n(x)=x^n\ln{x}$,  $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find
$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_n^{(n)}(\frac{1}{n})}{n!}
$$

My idea is by Leibniz product rule
$$
\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\ln{\frac{1}{n}}\right]^{(n)}=\overset{n}{\underset{k=0}{\sum}}\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!\cdot n^{-2n-k}
$$
Since n approaches to infinity, I check the n-th term, $n!\cdot n^{-n}$.

With the denominator, $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-n}= e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}(-n\ln{n})}=0$$

I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Does $f_n^{(n)}$ represent the $n$th derivative?

Comment: @David Raveh Yeah

Comment: Hint/Sketch: By taking the first derivative of $f_n(x)$, show that the sequence of functions $u_k(x) = \frac{f_k^{(k)}(x)}{k!}$ satisfies $u_k(x) =  u_{k-1}(x) + \frac1k$ and $u_0(x) = \ln x$.  Use that to show $u_n(1/n) = H_n - \ln n$.  Then evaluate the limit.

Comment: I don't see how you don't have a $\log(1/n)$ in your $n$th derivative. The $\log$ doesn't vanish at any stage.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Oh, I see. I miscalculated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, $$f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}\ln x +x^{n-1}$$ we get:

$$f_n^{(n)}(x)=n f_{n-1}^{(n-1)}(x)+(n-1)!$$

So if $a_n(x)=f_n^{(n)}(x)$ then:
$$a_n(x)=na_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)!$$

$$a_n(x)=n(n-1)a_{n-2}(x)+n(n-2)!+(n-1)!$$

Repeating:

$$a_n(x)=n!\log x+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{k}$$

So:

$$\frac{a_n(1/n)}{n!}=-\log (n) +\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k,$$

which converges to $\gamma,$ the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

Answer (score 1):

The notation $f_n^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is horrid and an invitation for confusion, but I'm pretty sure it means
$$\left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f_n\right]\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
i.e. differentiate first and then evaluate the result at $x=1/n$.
By writing
$$\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\ln{\frac{1}{n}}\right]^{(n)}$$
you seem to be interpreting it as something like
$$\lim_{u\to n} \frac{d^n}{du^n} \left[f_n\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)\right]$$
(compose $f$ with $\frac{1}{u}$ first and then differentiate) which is probably not what the problem intends.

In any case, a hint for your original problem: try to first work out an expression for the $k$th derivative of $x^n \log x$.

Comment: No explanation at all for the downvote?

Comment: yeah people keep downvoting posts with no explanation even though its completely correct

Comment: Maybe because I didn't spoil the full solution? But I did what the OP asked (found the error in *their* attempted solution). Dunno.

Comment: @user7530 MSE is not the site it used to be anymore.

Comment: No worry, I give you an upvote. Now it's draw. LOL

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
(z^n\ln z)^{(n)}&=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(z^n)^{(n-k)}(\ln z)^{(k)}\\
&=n!\ln z+\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{n!}{k!}z^k(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!z^{-k}\\
&=n!\left(\ln z+\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\right)
\end{align}$

So,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{f_n^{(n)}(1/n)}{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}-\ln(n)=\gamma,$$
is Euler-Mascheroni constant due to [this observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614504/how-to-prove-sum-k-1nn-choose-k-frac-1k1k-sum-k-1n-frac1/4614514#4614514).

Comment: It's exactly what I tried, but I miscalculated. Nice. But why there is $(-1)^{k-1}$ ? It's supposed to be removed?